# Among $52$ distinct integers, prove that there exist two, such that their sum is divisible by $100$ or their difference is.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

This has been a head-scratcher for a few days, and I avoided looking it up. Here's what I came up with today (feedback appreciated)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, your question is a specific case of [Given any $n+2$ integers, show that there exist two of them whose sum, or else whose difference, is divisible by $2n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3086834/602049).

Comment: I love it! And one of the responses is easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

The given integers $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{52}\}$ 
produce remainders, $\{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_{52}\}$ 
upon division by $100$. 
If two of these remainders, $r_i,r_j$ are equal
the difference of their corresponding integers 
$(a_i - a_j) \equiv (r_i-r_j) \equiv 0 \pmod {100}$ and the
conjecture is proven.

If, on the other hand the sequence $\{r_i\}$ is distinct, 
we have $52$ distinct numbers in the range
$R_{100}=\{0,1,2,\dots,99\}$. 
We define $49$ favorable 'bins' labeled with
a pair of one smaller and one larger number
$[1,99],[2,98],\dots,[49,51]$ such that the
sum of these numbers is $100$.
We assign each number from $\{r_i\}$ to 
exactly one of these 'bins' if $r_i$ equals
the smaller number or the larger.

Eliminating two possible remainders, $(0,50)$ whose
'favorable' pairs are outside the range $R_{100}$
we're left with at least $50$ remainders
that each belong to the $49$ 'bins'.

According
to the pigeonhole principle, one
'bin' must hold *at least* $2$ such remainders.
But since $\{r_i\}$ is distinct, 
this bin contains *exactly* $2$ remainders
hence the sum of the
two corresponding integers is a multiple of $100$.
■

Comment: It works just fine.  Note, however, that the first paragraph is unnecessary.  We can start with the $51$ "bins" $$\{0\}, \{1,99\}, \{2,98\}, \ldots, \{49,51\}, \{50\}$$ and note the remainders of the $52$ numbers must land in these bins.  By the pigeonhole principle, at least two remainders must land in the same bin, giving the same conclusion.

Comment: I’d make one small change. What’s important isn’t that one bin contains **exactly** two remainders, but rather that it contains two **distinct** remainders, since that’s what ensures that you have two remainders whose sum is $100$. That said, what you have is correct and clear.